# SDL Renderer argument for texture but not needed for surface

Tags: c++, sdl, game-engine, sdl-2

I am studying the basics of SDL, then I fell into this doubt. I learned that SDL texture is the GPU counterpart of SDL surface which uses CPU. But for getting a surface no renderer argument is given, simply the asset to be loaded was given as the argument. But for converting a surface to texture renderer argument was needed. What am I missing here?

```
SDL_Surface* pTempSurface=SDL_LoadBMP("image.bmp");
SDL_Texture* pTexture=SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(m_pRenderer,pTempSurface);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SDL_Surface` doesn't use `SDL_Renderer`, it's only used by/for `SDL_Texture`. `SDL_Surfaces` are copied from memory to the screen buffer with `SDL_Flip`. So when loading a bitmap into a surface no renderer is needed (indeed renderers did not exist before SDL 2.0), but when you use `CreateTextureFromSurface` you need to tell the function the renderer context into which the texture should be loaded.

Maybe not the best explanation, but I hope you get the difference.

If you are familiar with SDL 1.2 but not 2.0 the [Migration guide](https://wiki.libsdl.org/MigrationGuide) should help you.